# jquery toggleClass does not switch css classes when navbar-toggle is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have a div like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-2 login-form" style="margin-top:35px !important">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block user-actions user-actions-show">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block user-actions user-actions-show" style="margin-top:5px;">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to switch from `user-actions-show` class to `user-actions-off` class which is used for buttons, when the the `navbar-toggle` is clicked by using jQuery toggleClass:

```
<script>
        $(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
            $("user-actions-show").toggleClass("user-actions-off");
        })
</script>
```

And this is how the class `.user-actions-off` looks like:

```
.user-actions-off{
     display:none;
}
```

But now the problem is it does not work out.

So what am I doing wrong here? How can I properly hide those buttons when the `navbar-toggle`  is clicked?

This is the `navbar-toggle` class:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Which element has this `.navbar-toggle` class?

Comment: @kiner_shah Sorry I forgot to add it, plz check the **UPDATE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `.` in your script.

Change
`$("user-actions-show").toggleClass("user-actions-off");`

to `$(".user-actions-show").toggleClass("user-actions-off");`

That should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class whose name is `.hide` and toggle it to your `$(".user-actions-show")`; it'll override your existing CSS property to latest CSS property.